# GZip Decompress - каков механизм обработки?

Tags: c#, gzip

Написал метод, который по идее должен обрабатывать блоки, запакованные GZip

Беда в том, что на выходе я получаю пустой массив байт. Где ошибка в этом коде?

```
 private void DecompressionBlock(object x)
    {
        int i = (int)x;

        int _DecompressSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(iDecompressSize[i], 0);            
        int _CompressSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(iCompressSize[i], 0);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", _DecompressSize);  //1024
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", _CompressSize);    //732
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", firstBuff[i].Length); //732


        secondBuff[i] = new byte[_DecompressSize];

        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream ds = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                ds.Read(firstBuff[i], 0, _CompressSize);                    
            }
            secondBuff[i] = output.ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", secondBuff[i].Length); //0 
        }
    }
```

Если написать:

```
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream(secondBuff[i]))
```

Во время работы возникает исключение, и ругань на "магическое число" GZip

В компрессоре я отдельно запаковывал каждый массив байтов GZip-ом, и добавлял на стадии записи в фал перед ним блоки с размерами, при чтении я эти данные читаю, и записываю в массив целый не тронутый никем блок для того же gZip.

Может я что-то упустил из виду?

Вот метод компрессии:

```
private void CompressionBlock(object x)
    {                   
        int i = (int)x;

        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            long _outLength;
            using (GZipStream cs = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                cs.Write(firstBuff[i], 0, firstBuff[i].Length);
                _outLength = output.Length;              
            }
            secondBuff[i] = new byte[_outLength];
            secondBuff[i] = output.ToArray();

            // Запишем размер сжатого блока
            int _sizeBlock = secondBuff[i].Length;
            Console.WriteLine("Размер сжатого блока - {0}", _sizeBlock);
            iCompressSize[i] = new byte[4];
            iCompressSize[i] = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sizeBlock);
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас ошибка декомпресии 100% в `DecompressionBlock`. Ошибка 1. Вы создали MemStream который пустой, и пытаетесь с него читать. Ошибка 2 - вы считываете сжатый_зазмер вместо несжатого.

Comment: В DecompressionBlock у вас во многих местах перепутан входящий буфер с исходящим.  "Если написать" - написали вы **правильно** но с оговоркой, что secondBuff чистить `new` не надо. Начертите схемку что куда. Возможно перепишите процедуру с нуля. Как сложили пазл - так и в обратном порядке нужно раскладывать.

Comment: Строка `secondBuff[i] = new byte[_outLength];` удалить и там и там и забыть, она в 2 "лишняя" а в 1 приводит к сбою. Строка `iCompressSize[i] = new byte[4];` - тоже ненужна.

Comment: @ nick_n_a Наверное надо добавить: Я хочу подсунуть в GZipStream сжатый массив байтов из firstBuff[i], чтобы распаковать эти байты в secondBuff[i]. Допустимо ли вообще такое использование? Или байты необходимо обязательно помещать в FileStream?

Comment: Вы правильно сказали, но неправильно делаете. Вместо сжатого массива вы ему подсунули ему массив нулей такогоже размера - вот он и ругается на magic ( "магическое число" ). А потом подумали подумали - и подсунули вообще пустой стрим - и на выходе он вам ответил пустым масивом. Сделайте то что я написал в 3-ем сообщении, и верните масив в конструктор. Дальше получится.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо )